# itertools.product how to generate an n-dimensional array as defined by a tuple

Tags: python, matrix, tuples, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I wish to use itertools.product (or similar), to generate a set of matrix addresses (as tuples) from an initial tuple.

For instance..

```
 (5,)  # return the addresses for a 1-dimensional matrix of 5 columns,
 (4,3) # return the addresses for a 2-dimensional matrix of 4 columns and 3 rows.
 (5, 3, 2) # ditto for a 3D matrix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take, for example, the tuple `init_tuple` set to `(4, 3)`

```
# TL;DR
values = product(*[range(0, i) for i in init_tuple])
```

How does this work?

```
product([1,2],[3,4]). # generates the cross product.
>(1, 3)
>(1, 4)
>(2, 3)
>(2, 4)
```

So I wanted the cross product of the ranges `(0, i)` for each `i` in the tuple. 
Which means I want something like this..

```
product([0,1,2,3],[0,1,2])
```

Getting a list of ranges for each i in the tuple is pretty much plain English.

```
[range(0, i) for i in init_tuple]
>[range(0, 3), range(0, 4)]
```

Providing the list as parameters is just a `*` away. (Parameter unpacking is cool).

```
values = product(*[range(0, i) for i in init_tuple])


>(0, 0)
>(0, 1)
>(0, 2)
>(0, 3)
>(1, 0)
>(1, 1)
>(1, 2)
>(1, 3)
>(2, 0)
>(2, 1)
>(2, 2)
>(2, 3)
```